# How to restart Playing Audio in Java Sound API?

Tags: java, swing, audio, enums

I coded these two classes to test how I can use Java Sound API:

`enum SoundEffect` :  enumeration encapsulates all the sound I used.

`Class SoundEffectDemo` : to Test the SoundEffect enum in a Swing application

When I click on any button of  SoundEffectDemo (CALLING,RING,BUSY), the sound starts playing. And when I click on Stop Sound button, the sound is stopped.
But when I click on on any button of  SoundEffectDemo (CALLING,RING,BUSY) second time, there is no any sound.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public enum SoundEffect  {

    BUSY("resources/phone-busy.wav"),   
    CALLING("resources/phone-calling.wav"),         
    DISCONNECT("resources/phone-disconnect.wav"),
    RING("resources/telephone-ring.wav");  

    // Each sound effect has its own clip, loaded with its own sound file.
    private Clip clip;
    private URL url;
    private AudioInputStream audioInputStream;

    // Constructor to construct each element of the enum with its own sound file.
    SoundEffect(String soundFileName) {
        try {
            // Use URL (instead of File) to read from disk and JAR.
            this.url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(soundFileName);
            // Set up an audio input stream piped from the sound file.
            this.audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            // Get a clip resource.
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.addLineListener( new LineListener() {
                public void update(LineEvent evt) {
                    if (evt.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                        evt.getLine().close();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Play or Re-play the sound effect from the beginning, by rewinding.
    public void play() {

        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); 

    }

    public void stop(){

        clip.stop();   // Stop the player if it is still running
    }

    // Optional static method to pre-load all the sound files.
    static void init() {
        values(); // calls the constructor for all the elements
    }

    public boolean isActive(){

        return clip.isActive();
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {

        return clip.isOpen();
    }

    public void setFramePosition() {
        clip.setFramePosition(0);

    }

}




import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

// Testing the SoundEffect enum in a Swing application
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SoundEffectDemo extends JFrame {


    // Constructor
    public SoundEffectDemo() {
        // Pre-load all the sound files


        // Set up UI components
        Container cp = this.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));

        JButton btnSound1 = new JButton("CALLING");
        btnSound1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SoundEffect.CALLING.play(); 
            }
        });
        cp.add(btnSound1);

        JButton btnSound2 = new JButton("RING");
        btnSound2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SoundEffect.RING.play();
            }
        });
        cp.add(btnSound2);

        JButton btnSound3 = new JButton("BUSY");
        btnSound3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                SoundEffect.BUSY.play();
            }
        });
        cp.add(btnSound3);

        JButton btnSound4 = new JButton("Stop Sound ");
        btnSound4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for(SoundEffect value : SoundEffect.values()){
                    if(value.isActive()){
                        value.stop();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        cp.add(btnSound4);


        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Test SoundEffct");
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SoundEffectDemo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really clear what you mean by restart playing audio in java.

Your code is not relevant because from what it looks like, you've put everything in one single code block which makes it hard to read. You're missing several brackets. But back to your question. I've put together a simple class which does what you're asking for.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class PlaybackWAV {
    private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128000;
    private AudioInputStream audioStream;
    private AudioFormat audioFormat;
    private SourceDataLine sourceLine;
    private boolean running = false;

    /**
     * @param filename
     *            the name of the file that is going to be played
     */
    public synchronized void playSound(final String filename) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InputStream audioSrc = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
                    // add buffer for mark/reset support
                    InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(audioSrc);
                    audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);

                    audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();

                    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(
                            SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
                    sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                    sourceLine.open(audioFormat);

                    sourceLine.start();
                    running = true;

                    while (running) {
                        int nBytesRead = 0;
                        byte[] abData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        while (nBytesRead != -1) {
                            try {
                                nBytesRead = audioStream.read(abData, 0,
                                        abData.length);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
                                sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
                            }
                        }
                        if (running)
                            audioStream.reset();
                    }
                    sourceLine.drain();
                    sourceLine.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err
                            .printf("Exception occured while trying to playback file '%s'. (%s)%n",
                                    filename, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void stopSound() {
        this.running = false;
        if (sourceLine != null) {
            sourceLine.stop();
            sourceLine.drain();
            sourceLine.close();
        }
    }
}
```

There is two methods in this class, playSound which starts a new thread and plays a specific sound in your class folder and stopSound which obviously stops whatever sound that is currently playing. Here is a simple snippet which will create three buttons to play either sound of the three you have in your example.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Snippet extends JFrame {

    public Snippet(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        final PlaybackWAV player = new PlaybackWAV();
        JButton play1 = new JButton("CALLING");
        panel.add(play1);
        JButton play2 = new JButton("RING");
        panel.add(play2);
        JButton play3 = new JButton("BUSY");
        panel.add(play3);
        JButton play4 = new JButton("STOP");
        panel.add(play4);
        this.pack();

        play1.setAction(new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                player.stopSound();
                player.playSound("resources/phone-calling.wav");
            }
        });
        play2.setAction(new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                player.stopSound();
                player.playSound("resources/telephone-ring.wav");
            }
        });
        play3.setAction(new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                player.stopSound();
                player.playSound("resources/phone-busy.wav");
            }
        });
        play4.setAction(new AbstractAction(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                player.stopSound();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Snippet snippet = new Snippet();
        snippet.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Happy coding!

**EDIT:**

My apologies, I forgot to invoke the 'mark' method and therefor the reset method wouldn't work properly. Here is the new code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class PlaybackWAV {
    private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128000;
    private AudioInputStream audioStream;
    private AudioFormat audioFormat;
    private SourceDataLine sourceLine;
    private boolean running = false;

    /**
     * @param filename
     *            the name of the file that is going to be played
     */
    public synchronized void playSound(final String filename) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InputStream audioSrc = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
                    // add buffer for mark/reset support
                    InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(audioSrc);
                    audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);

                    audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();

                    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(
                            SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
                    sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                    sourceLine.open(audioFormat);

                    sourceLine.start();
                    running = true;

                    while (running) {
                        audioStream.mark(BUFFER_SIZE);
                        int nBytesRead = 0;
                        byte[] abData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        while (nBytesRead != -1) {
                            try {
                                nBytesRead = audioStream.read(abData, 0,
                                        abData.length);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
                                sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
                            }
                        }
                        if (running)
                            audioStream.reset();
                    }
                    sourceLine.drain();
                    sourceLine.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err
                            .printf("Exception occured while trying to playback file '%s'. (%s)%n",
                                    filename, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void stopSound() {
        this.running = false;
        if (sourceLine != null) {
            sourceLine.stop();
            sourceLine.drain();
            sourceLine.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still a little problem: when I  execute the example, I get this exception:       Exception occured while trying to playback file 'resources/phone-calling.wav'. (Resetting to invalid mark)
java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
 at PlaybackWAV$1.run(PlaybackWAV.java:56)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: @esprittn Okay, what is the duration of your audio file?

Comment: between 7 and 25 seconds

Comment: OK, does it always throw that exception? Or just randomly?

Comment: When the sound stop playing without clicking on STOP button

Comment: It works very well for me, it might because the AudioInputStream is reinitialized in another thread and for some reason the boolean running is not updating. You could try join the current thread and wait for it to finish or you could try adding the 'volatile' keyword for the running boolean. Something like this: `private volatile boolean running = false;`.

Comment: I tried private volatile boolean running = false; But same Exception occur.

Comment: @esprittn see my edit. My apologies. It should really work now.

Comment: Thanks for helping me the Exception still occur. But the program work fine.

Comment: So it still occurs after you've added the mark method? If your file exceeds 128000 bytes the mark will no longer be valid. If that is the case try increase the MAX_BUFFER variable. Other than that, good luck.

Comment: The way you are doing your marking is wrong, you are setting the read limit as the size of the buffer. That may only be worth like 2 seconds of audio. Furthermore, mark is not a reliable way to do seeking. It may not work at all. You need to test that `markSupported` is true.

Comment: @Radiodef well, in the example I added a comment 'add buffer for mark/reset support' and that is exactly what I did to add support for mark and reset methods. And since MAX_BUFFER is user-defined it is up to the user to define a appropriate size.

Comment: You shouldn't post code that's broken and not explain how it works.

Comment: @Radiodef well, feel free to edit my post. I just tried to provide a example. It might've not been the best but it still solved his problem to a certain extent. If this is incorrect, what is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

```
clip.addLineListener( new LineListener() {
    public void update(LineEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            evt.getLine().close();
        }
    }
});
```

This is probably not something you want to do, closing the line when it receives the stop event. After closing the Clip you would need to reopen it before it will play again.

Given what you're doing it's probably the case you don't need to close the line at all. Calling close indicates you are done with it.

See [`Line#close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html#close--) and [`AutoCloseable#close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close--).

A more appropriate interim action for your stop event would be [`drain`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#drain--) or [`flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#flush--). Then perhaps set the frame position to 0 if you want to "reset" it.

So remove the call to `close` and do something like

```
public void stop() {
    clip.stop();
    clip.flush();
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
}
```

As a side note, I noticed you aren't starting your Swing application on the Event Dispatch Thread. You should always [initialize your GUI with a call to `invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new SoundEffectDemo();
        }
    });
}
```

Thread safety with Swing is important because not doing it can lead to subtle errors that are difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks, it is working like I want. For Swing, I will use invokeLater next time. Thank you for these advances. Please do you know a good tutorial or book about Thread and Swing

Comment: The [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) (which I linked to in the answer) is very comprehensive.